# Differential equation $y'=-\frac{x+y}{x+2y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equation. How do you solve this ?

$$y'=-\frac{x+y}{x+2y}$$

set $u = \dfrac yx$, then $y' = u'x + u$,

$$u'x + u = -\frac{1+u}{1+2u}$$
$$u'x = -\frac{2u^2+2u+1}{1+2u}$$
$$\frac{(1+2u)u'}{2u^2+2u+1} = -\frac1x$$

I solved it so far but I do not know anymore

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Please **can you edit your question**, don't put vital details about a question into the comments.

Comment: [Separable equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables), fairly standard.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to proceed here would be to make an observation: the numerator of the left hand side is half the derivative of the denominator. In particular:

$$(2u^2+2u+1)'=(4u+2)u'$$

This leads one to conclude that the left hand side is simply the derivative of $\frac{1}{2}\log (2u^2+2u+1)$. So now you can just integrate both sides (don't forget the integration constant!), and you will see that you end up with a very nice 2nd order algebraic equation you can solve for $u$.

This kind of observation might seem tricky at first but it's something you should always be looking out for and it really isn't such a big deal after some practice.

Answer (score 2):

I like just using differentials straightforwardly.  I always start by getting rid of denominators and distributing.

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x - y}{x + 2y} \\
dy\, (x + 2y) = (-x - y)\,dx \\
x\,dy + 2y\,dy = -x\, dx - y\,dx
$$

At this point, I like to identify differentials which don't match the variables and see if I can get those into a common form (i.e., product or quotient rule form).  Here, we have $x\,dy$ and $y\,dx$ which are the components of the product rule $d(xy)$.

$$
x\,dy + y\,dx + 2y\,dy + x\,dx = 0 \\
d(xy) + 2y\,dy + x\,dx = 0 \\
\int d(xy) + 2y\,dy + x\,dx = \int 0 \\
xy + y^2 + \frac{x^2}{2} = C
$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
y'&=-\frac{x+y}{x+2y}\\
xy'+2yy'&=-x-y\\
y+xy'+2yy'&=-x\\
(xy+y^2)'&=-x
\end{align*}
So if you denote $z=xy+y^2$, you have
$$z'=-x$$
and you can get that
\begin{align*}
z&=-\frac{x^2}2+C\\
y^2+yx+\frac{x^2}2-C&=0
\end{align*}
and now you can find $y$ using the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula):
$$y=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{4C-x^2}}2.$$

For comparison, here is what you get [in WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D-%5Cfrac%7Bx%2By%7D%7Bx%2B2y%7D).

You can also check what you get after typing y'=-(x+y)/(x+2y) into [Mathematical Assistant on Web - Ordinary differential equations](http://um.mendelu.cz/maw-html/index.php?lang=en&form=ode#). Here is [link to the output](http://um.mendelu.cz/maw/ode/ode.php?lang=en&ip=&referer=http%3A%2F%2Fum.mendelu.cz%2Fmaw-html%2Fmenu.php&akce=0&ode=-%28x%2By%29%2F%28x%2B2y%29&ode2=x%2Ay%27%2By-x%3D0&output=html&output2=html&output3=pdf&internal=nosavelog).

Answer (score 1):

Before solving the DE, you need to know the total differential:

$$dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} dy$$

The idea is that, you need to rewrite the DE in the form of

$$P dx + Q dy = 0$$

and test whether this form satisfies the condition of total differential, which is

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$$

You can find more information about this in any multivariable calculus textbook.

So, from the DE

$$ y’ = - \frac{x+y}{x+2y} $$

we have

$$(x+y)dx + (x+2y)dy = 0$$

Then let

$$P(x,y) = x + y$$

$$Q(x,y) = x + 2y$$

we have

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} =   1  = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$$

Thus, let $F = F(x,y)$, then we have

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = P(x,y) = x + y$$

and

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = Q(x,y) = x + 2y$$

So we get

$$F = \int (x + y) dx = \frac{1}{2} x^2 + xy + f_1(y) \cdots (1)$$

and

$$F = \int (x + 2y) dy = xy + y^2 + f_2(x) \cdots (2)$$

Hence, combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, we have

$$F = \frac{1}{2} x^2 + xy + y^2$$

And then, since $dF = (x+y)dx + (x+2y)dy = 0$, we get

$$F = \frac{1}{2} x^2 + xy + y^2 = C$$

where $C$ is a constant.

Hope this helps to you.

Answer (score 1):

To continue the method in the question statement, we're effectively trying to evaluate the integral
$$\int \frac{(2 u + 1) \,du}{2 u^2 + 2 u + 1}.$$ Completing the square of the denominator suggests the translation substitution $v := u + \frac12$, giving
$$4 \int \frac{v \,dv}{4 v^2 + 1},$$
and the substitution $w = 4 v^2 + 1$ yields
$$\frac12 \int \frac{dw}{w} = \frac12 \log |w| + K = \frac12 \log(2 u^2 + 2 u + 1) + K ,$$
so $$\frac12 \log(2 u^2 + 2 u + 1) = -\log|x| + C .$$
Exponentiating both sides and squaring gives
$$2 u^2 + 2 u + 1 = \frac{D}{x^2},$$ where $D := e^{2 C}$, or
$$2 \left(\frac yx\right)^2 + 2 \left(\frac yx\right) + 1 = \frac{D}{x^2},$$
or
$$x^2 + 2 x y + 2 y^2 = D ,$$
which is an ellipse. Applying the quadratic formula gives $y$ as functions of $x$.

More generally, the same technique applies to differential equations of the form
$$y' = \frac{a y + b x}{c y - a x},$$ and the solution curves are conic sections whose type depends on the sign of $a^2 + bc$.